# Using Scipy Least Squares to best fit data against shifted power curve

Tags: numpy, least-squares

I'm new to Python/Scipy/Numpy.

I've successfully used an example from here to smooth data using least squares method.  But in a couple of cases it's accuracy is off at the extreme ends.

It seems a Shifted Power Curve is a better fit but I'm having problems with syntax on the **`a(x-b)^c`** function and am not sure this'll work with the `log10` method.

Current code is:

```html
from scipy import *
from scipy import optimize
#                                         # READ DATA FROM CSV FILE
DIA, FlowRate =  genfromtxt('#ThisDataFile#', delimiter=',', unpack='true')
#                                         # CONVERT DATA TO LOG ITS MORE ACCURATE
logx = log10(DIA)
logy = log10(FlowRate)                    #crlf#
#                                         # define our (line) fitting function
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0] + p[1] * x
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: (y - fitfunc(p, x))
pinit = [5.0, -5.0]
out = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, pinit,
                       args=(logx, logy), full_output=1)
pfinal1 = out[0]
amp1 = 10.0**pfinal1[0]

print(amp1, pfinal1[1])
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks
Peter

### Update:

Sample data ( on measured ) pressure:

```
DIA  = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
flow = [ 58.33254,
         30.11954,
         16.02723,
          9.47614,
          5.75362,
          3.63373,
          2.37532,
          1.58426
         ]
```

Comment: I fit the data you posted to a double exponential, no logs needed, with excellent results:      y = a * exp(bx) + c * exp(dx)

    Fitting target of lowest sum of squared absolute error = 9.8500663128197066E-02

    a =  2.1159998407921812E+01
    b = -3.3158309848989914E-01
    c =  9.7577758407802179E+01
    d = -8.1563989368844170E-01

Comment: Thanks James. I tried the double exponential method in Excel but wasn't able to get close.

Comment: Tried:from scipy import *
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

##READ DATA FROM CSV FILE
x, y =  genfromtxt('#ThisDataFile#', delimiter=',', unpack='true')

def f(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c * np.exp(d * x)

def residual(p, x, y):
    return y - f(x, *p)

p0 = [1., 1., 1.,1.]
popt, pcov = optimize.leastsq(residual, p0, args=(x, y))

print (popt) ...... but got a warning of too many iterations and the result was way off............ as I say I'm new to this method so I'm sure it's my approach more that your method.

Comment: Just to clarify, the data represents pressure changes across different sized orifices for a fixed flow rate. I simplified x as each of the 8 even  steps represented 1/32". Actual dimensions in inches were 0.15625,0.1875,0.21875,0.25,0.28125,0.3125,0.34375,0.375. Using a simple ax^b I find the results close but not close enough on the smallest and largest diameters. If I dial these into Curve Expert Pro the Shifted Power curve is very accurate but I can't reproduce it in Scimpy.  I have some 5,000 data sets to run and have been automating through a command line routine called from ColdFusion.

Comment: Excel's solver is not, ah, of great renown - I used a Python solver with a genetic algorithm front end to scipy's Levenberg-Marquardt solver.  The genetic algorithm searched error space for initial parameter estimates for the L-M solver, Excel's solver does not do this.  If you test the equation and parameter values from my comment you will see excellent smooth results.

Comment: I just realized that Excel's solver should work if you start it with initial values near those that I gave for the double exponential.  This is worth a quick test.  You will not need to enter the entire parameter value, just use up to the first decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data
pressure = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
flow="58.33254,30.11954,16.02723,9.47614,5.75362,3.63373,2.37532,1.58426"

Comment: Sorry, new to forums - I answered instead of adding a comment!